# Opera for dual boot Windows 10 & Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, opera

I'm using currently more Opera than FF, I think with FF, you can use the same profile directory so both Windows 10 & Ubuntu can use the same configuration/history, etc. Is it possible to do the same with Opera? I tried the net but found nothing, can you please point me to the right direction? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've got two suggestion:

1. Sync your browsing data in Opera
2. Linking  the profiles (might not work)

---

1. > When you switch between several computers and smartphones, you don't have to worry about losing track of an interesting web page. Learn how to sync bookmarks, favorite sites on the Speed Dial and tabs to keep important browsing info at your fingertips in Opera! [[1]](http://www.opera.com/computer/features/sync)
2. Also, you can always use linking, The default Windows installation location is:

   ```
   %PROGRAMFILES%\Opera
   ```

   For linux it's `~/share/opera`.

   User settings in windows are saved into `%PROGRAMFILES%\Opera\profile`, enter this path into your file explorer in windows, get the real path, and use that to create a sym for your Ubuntu while your windows partition is mounted:

   ```
   ln -s /real/path/to/profile ~/share/profile
   ```

   now it should do the trick for you.

sources: [2](http://www.opera.com/docs/operafilesnix/), [3](http://www.opera.com/docs/operafiles/)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I tried the sync option previously (long time ago), and the trouble I had is the bookmark and favorites are all there, but they are all messed up (I organized in folders/subfolders in Windows, but when I got to Ubuntu, it was all listed alphabetically, not in folders/subfolders any longer, that's why I stopped using it. I'll give it a try your 2nd option, I'll post it back after test. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I'm to an opera user, however the best option in all browsers in my opinion is their sync... give it a shot again ;)

Comment: Thanks again for your input, just a curiosity, which browser do you recommend for someone using Win 10 & Ubuntu? I liked a lot FF but it seems it's getting too heavy and slow.

Comment: I was an opera user I don't know maybe 8 years ago, then I switched to Firefox, and I'm still using it, you should go with whatever fits your needs.